# How can I capture stdout and stderr in the browser?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to capture stderr and stdout in the browser from the currently executing javascript.

This will be for a live code editor.

Comment: Browser does not have any of that. JS does no echo any content, it either prints in console or modifies text nodes

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Answer (score 5):

JS has no `stdout` or `stderr` - it just has the `console`.

It is possible to override `console.log()` with your own function that does whatever processing you want, and ideally then pass the log message to the original `console.log` function.     Ditto for `console.error`.

For example:

```
(function() {
    const log_orig = console.log;

    console.log = function() {
        log_orig.call(console, 'log called with ' arguments.length + ' parameters');
        log_orig.apply(console, arguments);
    }
})();  // IIFE
```

Comment: What about errors?

Comment: @chovy errors are typically reported using `console.error`, so you'd duplicate the above code with `log` replaced by `error`.

Comment: even like if the code doesn't compile? I know if they specificaly call `console.error` i can get it.

Comment: that's a different problem that wasn't in your original question - ISTR you can trap `window.onerror` on some browsers to catch JS interpreter errors

Comment: see e.g. this old link - https://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/how-to-catch-javascript-errors-with-window-onerror-even-on-chrome-and-firefox/

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Any output and errors that browser outputs are not exposed to JS.